# Function when multiple elements have been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click, element

I want a to have an animation only when seven elements have been click. Here is the code but it doesn't work:

```
var animp5 = function () {
    var i = 0;
    $("#ans1_p5").on('click', function () {
        i = i + 1;
        $("#ans1_p5").fadeOut(800);
        $("#correct1_p5").fadeIn(1000);
    });

    $("#ans2_p5").on('click', function () {
        i = i + 1;
        $("#ans2_p5").fadeOut(800);
        $("#correct2_p5").fadeIn(1000);
    });

    $("#ans3_p5").on('click', function () {
        i = i + 1;
        $("#ans3_p5").fadeOut(800);
        $("#correct3_p5").fadeIn(1000);
    });

    $("#ans5_p5").on('click', function () {
        i = i + 1;
        $("#ans5_p5").fadeOut(800);
        $("#correct4_p5").fadeIn(1000);
    });

    $("#ans7_p5").on('click', function () {
        i = i + 1;
        $("#ans7_p5").fadeOut(800);
        $("#correct5_p5").fadeIn(1000);
    });

    $("#ans9_p5").on('click', function () {
        i = i + 1;
        $("#ans9_p5").fadeOut(800);
        $("#correct6_p5").fadeIn(1000);
    });

    $("#ans10_p5").on('click', function () {
        i = i + 1;
        $("#ans10_p5").fadeOut(800);
        $("#correct7_p5").fadeIn(1000);
    });

    if (i === 7) {
        $("#ans4").fadeOut(800);
        $("#ans6").fadeOut(800);
        $("#ans8").fadeOut(800);
        $("#wrong1_p5").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#wrong2_p5").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#wrong3_p5").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#cor_p5").fadeIn(1000);
    }
};
```

I have tried other solutions (like `.data('clicked')` or `.attr('clicked')` but they didn't work either.

Comment: instead of trying to put a listener on a ton of elements based on id... it would be better to use a single listener based on a class name... then if something is clicked you could toggle class "clicked" or something like that on that element... then count `$(".clicked").length`

Comment: if you share your dom it might be easier to tell what is going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use observer design pattern in javascript to achieve this the right way.

First create handlers, subscribe and execute functions and then you can subscribe waht ever you like in your case its comparison i===7. execute fade.execute after every click to validate.

Also it's advisable to use class selectors than id selectors in your case. As id selectors will be unmanageable and you will end up with a lot of duplicate code.

But for the sake of your question observer is your way to go.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5229Ls59/4/)

```
function Fade() { // Create Fade handlers
  this.handlers = [];  // observers
}

Fade.prototype = { // define subscribe and execute
   subscribe: function(fn) {
     this.handlers.push(fn);
   },
   execute: function(o, thisObj) {
      var scope = thisObj || window;
      this.handlers.forEach(function(item) {
        item.call(scope, o);
      });
   }
};

var fade = new Fade();
fade.subscribe(function(){ // pass function you want to subscribe
   console.log(i);
   if(i===7){
          $("#ans4").fadeOut(800);
          $("#ans6").fadeOut(800);
          $("#ans8").fadeOut(800);
          $("#wrong1_p5").fadeIn(1000);
          $("#wrong2_p5").fadeIn(1000);
          $("#wrong3_p5").fadeIn(1000);
          $("#cor_p5").fadeIn(1000);
      }
});

var animp5 = (function(){
    var i = 0;
    $("#ans1_p5").on('click',function(){
        i=i+1;
        $("#ans1_p5").fadeOut(800);
        $("#correct1_p5").fadeIn(1000);
        fade.execute(); // execute to check if condition met
    });

    $("#ans2_p5").on('click',function(){    
        i=i+1;
        $("#ans2_p5").fadeOut(800);
        $("#correct2_p5").fadeIn(1000);
        fade.execute();
    });

    $("#ans3_p5").on('click', function(){
        i=i+1;
        $("#ans3_p5").fadeOut(800);
        $("#correct3_p5").fadeIn(1000);
        fade.execute();
    });  

    $("#ans5_p5").on('click', function(){
        i=i+1;
        $("#ans5_p5").fadeOut(800);
        $("#correct4_p5").fadeIn(1000);
        fade.execute();
    });  

    $("#ans7_p5").on('click', function(){
        i=i+1;
        $("#ans7_p5").fadeOut(800);
        $("#correct5_p5").fadeIn(1000);
        fade.execute();
    });  

    $("#ans9_p5").on('click', function(){
        i=i+1;
        $("#ans9_p5").fadeOut(800);
        $("#correct6_p5").fadeIn(1000);
        fade.execute();
    });

    $("#ans10_p5").on('click', function(){
        i=i+1;
        $("#ans10_p5").fadeOut(800);
        $("#correct7_p5").fadeIn(1000);
        fade.execute();
    });  

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.
As I have not much experience working with jquery I was unable to code your solution but I found a new one that works perfect. I put the "if" inside every click function so each time I click, code checks if the condition has been fulfilled and once this happens run the appropriate code.
Thanks again